# How to filter elements by values from another arrays

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON data:

```json
{
    "services": [
        {
            "name": "B1",
            "criticality": "BC"
        },
        {
            "name": "B2",
            "criticality": "BC"
        },
        {
            "name": "M1",
            "criticality": "MC"
        },
        {
            "name": "M2",
            "criticality": "MC"
        },
        {
            "name": "M3",
            "criticality": "MC"
        },
        {
            "name": "M4",
            "criticality": "MC"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "from_name": "B1",
            "to_name": "M1"
        },
        {
            "from_name": "M1",
            "to_name": "M2"
        },
        {
            "from_name": "M2",
            "to_name": "B2"
        },
        {
            "from_name": "M1",
            "to_name": "M3"
        },
        {
            "from_name": "M4",
            "to_name": "M2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the services those have `criticality==MC` and depends from other services with `criticality==MC`.

Output may look like the following: service and its dependencies

```json
{
  "M1": [
    "M2",
    "M3"
  ],
  "M4": [
    "M2"
  ]
}
```

(it could be an array instead of list)

How to do it?

---

When I dig into links, I lost information about services and vice versa:

```py
.links[] as $in | .services.[] | select(.name == $in.from_name) | select(.criticality == "MC")
```

will produce:

```json
{
  "name": "M1",
  "criticality": "MC"
}
{
  "name": "M2",
  "criticality": "MC"
}
```

But there is no information about `.links`.

Comment: Two questions: (1) In your sample output (apart from not being valid JSON), why isn't M2 also listed on top-level? (2) Do you want to track dependecies recursively, and if so, how would the output then look like? For instance, if B2 also had MC, and as M2 depends on B2, and M1 on M2,how would this be represented in the output (if you wanted to dig more than just one level deep)?

Comment: @pmf: (1) M2 isn't listed because it has no links where .to_name services has `criticality=MC`. Only `BC`.

Comment: @pmf: (2) no recursion dependencies is needed. But if it is possible to see an alternative solution with detection of all indirect dependencies from MC to any other MC, it would be nice!

Comment: @pmf: Fixed the answer to valid JSON. It is a array of maps (key is service name, value is array of its dependencies). Thanks, for mentioned mistake.

Comment: Could you share another example of having multiple dependecies i.e. `M2`, `M3`?

Comment: @Inian: yes, I have updated input and output data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
# find the MC services and put them into $mc
[ .services[] | select(.criticality == "MC") | .name ] as $mc | 

# filter links by having MC only in source and target
[ .links[] | select(.from_name | IN($mc[])) | select(.to_name | IN($mc[])) ] |

# group results by .from_name
group_by(.from_name) | map({(.[0].from_name):map(.to_name)}) | add
```

Check online: https://jqplay.org/s/AwFt0Ke7DLO